# How to setup Mitel Enhanced Integration with O365?

Tags: mitel

Migrating to the cloud in an O365 hybrid e-mail environment, but each e-mailbox that moves loses the ability to do Enhanced Integration with the Mitel phonesystem.

The system level e-mail configuration on the phonesystem points at the on-prem portion of our hybrid e-mail setup.  So, "forward" option works for voicemail as that's simple SMTP which gets relayed up to the cloud.  Enhanced Integration will work for e-mailboxes still on that on-prem server when pointed at it (as enhanced integration opens up server options instead of going through the default system e-mail configuration).  However, for migrated e-mailboxes the Enhanced Integration does not function whether pointed on-prem or cloud.

My searching thus far for information has only led me user level documents which have not been at all helpful.  Are there any special configuration for the O365/cloud environment?  I know a certain minimum software version is required, but we've met that requirement.  Could it be firewalling?  What protocols need to be allowed to the cloud from the phone system?  Any other setup concerns for a hybrid configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a problem with Multi Factor Authentication.  MiTel Enhanced Integration connects via IMAP.  Microsoft Cloud IMAP with MFA accounts requires that application specific passwords be setup.  The passwords are VERY application specific, my testing revealed that once used by an app it will not work for another, so apparently it can detect attempts to recycle as well.